# How to connect Document Library and crawled data in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, search, document-library

This is what I have installed.

1. SharePoint 2010, actually it was Search Server 2010 Express, is installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.
2. The crawling content source is connected to one of our File Server on the same network.

I am able to search folders and files from SharePoint home page, but I can't search them if I create a Document Library.

Am I going wrong way to search crawled data on Document Library? Should I just use the home page?

Comment: Does anybody have an idea for this? Even though it is not possible, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the crawled content either from the search box provided or from a search center by provisioning a new search site or you can write your own code as a web part to perform your search.  You may also use the search web service in code for a layered service based approach.

Comment: I was able to get crawled data result from MSSCrawlURL table in Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_### database in my SQL server. IS that the table that I need to use to create treeview web part?

Comment: It is not a good idea to do any development against SharePoint databases, use the SharePoint Object Model.  If you want to do custom search you can use Search Object Model or search.asmx web service to send queries to search service.